# Deserializing Non-Array Data Into An Array

Tags: json, json.net

I have no control over my data source. They have constructed a JSON string that should contain arrays, but it doesn't. Furthermore, they have named each property differently. I have tried everything I know but I'm at a loss trying to deserialize this.

```
{ "class-A" : { "property_0" : { "item1" : "data", "item2" : "data" }, "property_1" : { "item1" : "data", "item2" : "data" }, "property_2" : { "item1" : "data", "item2" : "data" } } }
```

This is supposed to be an array, so that I can deserialize it into an IEnumerable<property> but the lack of array brackets and the underscores/numbers appended to the property name are really throwing me off.

I have been able to deserialize the string into separate, numbered properties and then add them to a collection, but that won't work as the number of properties can get lengthy (on the order of 200 or more) and I don't know in advance how many properties will be included in the JSON string.

Is there a way to handle this deserialization using Newtonsoft-Json, so that it ignores the underscore/number in the property name and handles it as an array property name (alias) instead? I have control over constructing the model that represents the JSON string, but I'm not sure how that helps.

Comment: You need to request to your JSON provider for your requirements to make your life easier

Comment: it's valid on JSONLint.com by the way

Comment: Even if you can't change your data source, I think it would help people to answer the question if they knew what you wish your data looked like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JObject response = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
JEnumerable<JToken> jTokens = response["class-A"].Children();

IList<Property> properties = new List<Property>();

foreach (var jToken in jTokens)
{
    JsonProp jsonProp = jToken.First.ToObject<JsonProp>();

    Property property = new Property();

    property.Item1 = jsonProp.item1;
    property.Item2 = jsonProp.item2;

    properties.Add(property);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched and looks like you need a JSONConverter.

```
/// <summary>
/// A JsonConverter that respects the Name property of DataMember attributes
/// applied to enumeration members, falling back to the enumeration member
/// name where no DataMember attribute exists (or where a name has not
/// been supplied). Entirely experimental, use at your own risk.
/// 
/// Paul O'Neill, paul@pablissimo.com, 31/07/13
/// </summary>
public class DataMemberAwareEnumJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, IEnumerable<Tuple<object, string>>> _typeNameCache = 
        new Dictionary<Type, IEnumerable<Tuple<object, string>>>();

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsEnum;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type type, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return GetOutputValue(reader.Value.ToString(), type);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, GetOutputName(value));
    }

    private static string GetOutputName(object value)
    {
        Type type = value.GetType();
        if (!type.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Type is not an enumeration");
        }

        var map = GetOutputMap(type);
        var match = map.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item1.Equals(value));
        if (match != null)
        {
            return match.Item2;
        }
        else
        {
            // We're buggered if this is a flags enum so just return the string representation
            return value.ToString();
        }
    }

    private static object GetOutputValue(string serialised, Type type)
    {            
        if (!type.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Type is not an enumeration");
        }

        var map = GetOutputMap(type);
        var match = map.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item2.Equals(serialised));
        if (match != null)
        {
            // Immediate hit, just use it
            return match.Item1;
        }
        else
        {
            // No hit, which suggests a straight Enum.Parse should work 
            // (or fail because we've been supplied nonsense)
            return Enum.Parse(type, serialised);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Tuple<object, string>> GetOutputMap(Type type)
    {
        IEnumerable<Tuple<object, string>> enumOutputLookup = null;
        if (!_typeNameCache.TryGetValue(type, out enumOutputLookup))
        {
            // Index the type naively - it's unlikely we'll have more than a handful of
            // enum values per type
            List<Tuple<object, string>> outputNames = new List<Tuple<object, string>>();
            foreach (var field in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public))
            {
                var dataMemberAttribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(DataMemberAttribute)) as DataMemberAttribute;
                if (dataMemberAttribute != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataMemberAttribute.Name))
                {
                    outputNames.Add(new Tuple<object, string>(field.GetValue(null), dataMemberAttribute.Name));
                }
                else
                {
                    // No attribute, so go with the string representation of the field
                    outputNames.Add(new Tuple<object, string>(field.GetValue(null), field.Name));
                }
            }

            enumOutputLookup = outputNames;
            _typeNameCache[type] = outputNames;
        }

        return enumOutputLookup;
    }
}
```

From http://pablissimo.com/572/getting-newtonsoft-json-net-to-respect-the-datamember-name-property

and

https://gist.github.com/Pablissimo/6123242#file-datamemberawareenumjsonconverter

Comment: Oh, wow! I'm going to give it a try now and see what happens.

Comment: Well, it's not going to work the way it is because you still have to decorate every property with the new name, but I might be able to do something in the custom-converter (maybe using a String.StartsWith) to help.

Comment: Ok no problem I will delete this answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for but maybe it will give you some ideas.

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var jsonPathResult = jObject.SelectTokens("$.class-A.*");
var collection = new List<Items>();
jsonPathResult.ToList().ForEach(m => collection.Add(new Items { item1 = m.Values().ElementAt(0).ToString(), item2 = m.Values().ElementAt(1).ToString() }));
```

Where `Items` is

```
public class Items
{
    public string item1 { get; set; }
    public string item2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize it as a C# dictionary, so that the different property names end up as the keys.

```
class Items
{
    string item1;
    string item2;
}

Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Items>> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Items>>(json);
Dictionary<string, Items> classA = data["class-A"];
```

Then loop through all indexes and build the array:

```
List<Items> items = new List<Items>();
int i = 0;
while (classA.ContainsKey("property_" + i.ToString()))
{
    items.Add(classA["property_" + i.ToString()]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: I came up with the above solution before seeing your solution. I'll have to experiment with yours and see which has the better performance, if any.